# In-App Purchase crashes App after release

Tags: ios, debugging, crash, in-app-purchase

Apple has approved our first app that has In-App Purchases - however suddenly when a user taps the "Upgrade" button the app hangs momentarily and then crashes. By using the Console feature in XCode's Organizer I was able to obtain the following report:

```
Sep 18 15:12:48 iPad MyApp[53107] <Error>: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
    *** First throw call stack:
    (0x316f92a3 0x3958497f 0x31643e8d 0x54b23 0x335ec0c5 0x335ec077 0x335ec055 0x335eb90b 0x335ebe01 0x335145f1 0x33501801 0x3350111b 0x351f35a3 0x351f31d3 0x316ce173 0x316ce117 0x316ccf99 0x3163febd 0x3163fd49 0x351f22eb 0x33555301 0x4b81f 0x399bbb20)
Sep 18 15:12:48 iPad ReportCrash[53109] <Notice>: Formulating crash report for process MyApp[53107]
Sep 18 15:12:48 iPad com.apple.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.mycompany.MyApp[0x716c][53107]) <Warning>: (UIKitApplication:com.mycompany.MyApp[0x716c]) Job appears to have crashed: Abort trap: 6
Sep 18 15:12:48 iPad ReportCrash[53109] <Error>: libMobileGestalt copySystemVersionDictionaryValue: Could not lookup ReleaseType from system version dictionary
Sep 18 15:12:48 iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:com.mycompany.MyApp[0x716c]' exited abnormally with signal 6: Abort trap: 6
Sep 18 15:12:48 iPad ReportCrash[53109] <Notice>: Saved crashreport to /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/MyApp_2013-09-18-151248_iPad.plist using uid: 0 gid: 0, synthetic_euid: 501 egid: 0
```

This does not occur when I run the app on my device, and it must've worked when Apple review it or else they would not have cleared it for sale.

My guess it that my products array is null and when trying to purchase `_products[0]` (the only available one) it crashes.

**More Info:**
I followed [Ray Wenderlich's Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/21081/introduction-to-in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial) when adding In-App Purchases:

```
[[AppStoreHelper sharedInstance] requestProductsWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSArray *products) {
    if (success) {
        _products = products;
    }
    [refreshControl endRefreshing];
}];
```

To sum up: why does it only work in testing mode?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should provide more info about where that item array comes from, how it's populated and so on. But if the object at 0 is the only one you could use `item.lastObject` which simply returns nil if the array is empty and doesn't raise an exception (and doesn't crash).

Comment: @Rickye there we go. `_products.lastObject` seems like a good idea. I am still baffled as to why it never crashed during testing though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works now. I guess Apple's servers needed some time to process the purchase...

Comment: I am facing exactly the same problem. Could you please tell me how long time did it took for the in-apps to start working after the app came online ?

Comment: @LeoOlympian Apple approved my app on 2013-09-18 10:13AM and the In-App Purchases first discovered to work at 2013-09-19 6:00PM

Comment: Wow!! That's 32 hours delay!! We need to find a way to be able to sped up this process, because the first 2 days is the key period for the apps success!!

Comment: @LeoOlympian I've had an idea: maybe try to predict when the app will come out of review (this may help: http://reviewtimes.shinydevelopment.com/) and set the Availability Date to a few days past that date? 
Also with a new app version I think you can specify "I will release my app once it's approved" - waiting a few days might be the only way to work around this at the moment.